# Pi Zero W won't boot but file system on SD card seems fine

Tags: boot, hdmi, pi-zero-w, boot-issues

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot a Pi Zero W that just blinks (between 7 and 10 times) at me instead of booting? I DON'T have a mini HDMI connector so it's headless only.

I do have access to the SD card via another Linux box and all appears well with the file system...

any tips?!

many thanks

Comment: try another sd or try same sd in another pi.  appearances may deceive.

Comment: thanks. In the end I got the files I needed off it and reimaged the same SD card. All well now. Still don't know what went wrong. Suspect damage to the boot sector. Cheers!